# Count Lines Viewed from command 'less'

Tags: command-line, less

I run command `less`

```
ls /usr/bin | less
```

got many lines of directories.

```
2to3-
2to3-2.7
AssetCacheLocatorUtil
AssetCacheManagerUtil
AssetCacheTetheratorUtil
BuildStrings
CpMac
...
```

How to enumerate them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean `ls /usr/bin`? In any case, you can use the `-N` option:

```
ls /usr/bin | less -N
```

From `man less`:

```
   -N or --LINE-NUMBERS
          Causes a line number to be displayed at the  beginning  of  each
          line in the display.
```